# ExactTarget IMH FTUX

Tags: marketing-cloud

We are developing a Marketing Cloud App for the IMH (Interactive Marketing Hub), and at the moment we are not clear on how and where the FTUX (First Time User Experience) page should be implemented.
This is mainly because we don’t know how to emulate the installation process (the drag install) in development.
We tried few free applications and it seems that they don't have the FTUX page (after the installation they show directly in the marketing cloud environment).

This confuses us because according to ExactTarget documentation FTUX and SSO are the minimum requirements for a HubExchange app.

Any ides or clues that could point us in the right direction would be really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

HubExchange FTUX Page

Visit the HubExchange FTUX page for the FTUX Toolkit and guide to creating this page. Also to note, many free apps, eg ET Labs Apps, do not have FTUX pages with the same parameters as partner program pages.

See the FTUX main page for all things FTUX:

http://partner.hubexchange.com/#ftux-page-selection

Answer (score 0):

Utilizing the First Time User Experience (FTUX) template was not initially required for the inaugural partner applications. It was added as a required component to the HubExchange program after the inaugural Marketplace launch in July '13.

However, a number of the inaugural partners have still implemented the FTUX template. Litmus and ContentCTRL are two good examples of those who have utilized the FTUX toolkit in their app process.

Send any additional questions directly to the HubExchange team at hubexchange@exacttarget.com